# Convert Database into .csv file

Tags: android, database, csv

I'm trying to convert my database into a csv file but am having a crazy amount of trouble. I am about a year into coding so this has been very hard for me.

here is my code to make the csv file. It makes the file but For some reason it makes an empty file instead of a csv file with all the data from the database.

```
public class ExportDatabaseToCSV{

static Context context;
public ExportDatabaseToCSV(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
}

public static void exportDataBaseIntoCSV(){


    Database db = new Database(context);//here CredentialDb is my database. you can create your db object.
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");

    if (!exportDir.exists())
    {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(exportDir, "csvfilename.csv");

    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        SQLiteDatabase sql_db = db.getReadableDatabase();//here create a method ,and return SQLiteDatabaseObject.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = sql_db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Database.DATABASE_TABLE,null);
        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

        while(curCSV.moveToNext())
        {
            //Which column you want to exprort you can add over here...
            String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
        }

        csvWrite.close();
        curCSV.close();
    }
    catch(Exception sqlEx)
    {
        Log.e("Error:", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }
}
```

}

```
 try
    {

        File file = new File(exportDir, "csvfilename.csv");
        file .setReadable(true, false);
        file .setWritable(true,false);

        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        SQLiteDatabase sql_db = db.openOrCreateDatabase("community_service_Database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor curCSV = sql_db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Database.DATABASE_TABLE,null);
        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

        while(curCSV.moveToNext())
        {
            //Which column you want to export you can add over here...
            String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);

            csvWrite.close();
            curCSV.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception sqlEx)
    {
        Log.e("Error:", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The File constructor will already create the file for you.
You may need to set it to readable and writable.

```
File file = new File(exportDir, "csvfilename.csv");
file .setReadable(true, false);
file .setWritable(true,false);
```

I suggest you just extend an SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
  public static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
  {
    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
      super(context, "community_service_Database", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
    {
      String[] SqlStatements =
      {
        "CREATE TABLE TestTable (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test varchar(255) NOT null)"
      };

      for (int i = 0; i < SqlStatements.length; i++)
        database.execSQL(SqlStatements[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {

    }
  }
```

Change your implementation:

```
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
//here CredentialDb is my database. you can create your db object.
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");

if (!exportDir.exists())
{
  exportDir.mkdirs();
}


try
{

    File file = new File(exportDir, "csvfilename.csv");
    file .setReadable(true, false);
    file .setWritable(true,false);

    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    SQLiteDatabase sql_db = db.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor curCSV = sql_db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Database.DATABASE_TABLE,null);
    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

    while(curCSV.moveToNext())
    {
       //Which column you want to export you can add over here...
       String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
       csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);

       csvWrite.close();
       curCSV.close();
    }
}
catch(Exception sqlEx)
{
    Log.e("Error:", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
}
```